# Pass data from JSON to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I got this from a design tool we have at our service. This div class is suppose to be added on pages where we want to generate a Gauge chart with given information.

```
<div class="gauge" id="g0" data-settings='
  {
    "value": 9,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "units": "%",
    "limits": [
      {"from": 0, "to": 30, "color": "green", "label": "Low attrition"},
      {"from": 31, "to": 70, "color": "gray", "label": "Moderate attrition"},
      {"from": 71, "to": 100, "color": "red", "label": "High attrition"}
    ]
  }'
></div>
```

So what I need to learn is how I modify the values passed into data-settings here to make the Gauge chart more dynamic. I'm gonna get some data by parsing a JSON which I get from the backend.

```
var Data = JSON.parse("{{data_attrition|escapejs}}");
```

And this I want to pass into some of the variables in data-settings, for example change "value" from 9 to whatever I get from the backend.

Comment: How does the json get into your html in the first place?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I'll update the question with where I get the data from

Comment: @Ron I understand that, but I can't reproduce anything here because this chart is generated automatic from the design package we have inside the project. I just don't understand how I can change the values inside data-settings without "hard code" it. I want it to be dynamical. I get some data from the backend which should be feeded to this somehow

Comment: you can manipulate your JSON via JavaScript, or via a backed language, and dynamically output it to HTML's frontend either by JS GET/POST or if your backend is generating the output HTML, just add the data where it needs to be. There are many tutorials on this, did you research?

Comment: @Ron if you say it's "just to add the data where it needs to be" how would I do that inside the data-settings then? I already have what data I need from my backend, just don't know how to add that in data-settings. For example, my "value" here is just hardcoded and I want to pass my data from the backend to it

Comment: `$('#g0').data('settings', variable_that_holds_the_new_json);`

Answer (score 0):

I see you use JS, so one option is to utilize jquery's `.get()` method to make a request to thee server to get a the JSON in the form you need (based on some parameters maybe), and the use `.html()` or `data()` properties to set the data dynamically.
Check this as a start: https://api.jquery.com/data/